# Pick a next item from NSArray and then start over

Tags: objective-c

I need to toggle three different font sizes in the view controller for terms and conditions screen in an endless loop (13 , 15, 17..13, 15, 17..etc..). The screen is pretty simple, just text on full screen and a button in the navigation bar that when pressed, triggers and event handled in action.

The three fonts are represented by three NSString constants.

```
-(IBAction)toggleFontSize:(id)sender
{
    if (self.currentFontIdentifier == regularFontIdentifier)
    {
        self.currentFontIdentifier = largeFontIdentifier;
    }
    else if (self.currentFontIdentifier == largeFontIdentifier)
    {
       self.currentFontIdentifier = smallFontIdentifier;
    }
    else
    {
       self.currentFontIdentifier = regularFontIdentifier;
    }

    self.termsAndConditionsTextView.font = [[BrandingManager sharedManager] fontWithIdentifier:self.currentFontIdentifier];
}
```

This code works (for now :)), but it's a nice Mediterranean IF yacht.I am wondering if there is some more mature approach. I already see the stakeholders changing their mind and adding a 4th font size. I want it to be manageable better, so basically once they add a new size I would only add it into some Array and that would be it.

Any ideas for a more mature algorithm?

Comment: If you showed the code to do it the "long" way we'd have some clue as to what you're talking about.

Comment: You mean like `x = (x + 1) % 3;`?

Comment: @HotLicks I made the question comprehensible.

Comment: And I answered it.  Other than you should put the fonts in an array and index that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare an instance variable for the current selected index and an array for the three fonts (small, regular and large) and try this:

```
-(IBAction)toggleFontSize:(id)sender {
    _currentSelectedIndex = (_currentSelectedIndex + 1) % 3;
    self.currentFontIdentifier = _fontIdentifiers[_currentSelectedIndex];
    self.termsAndConditionsTextView.font = [[BrandingManager sharedManager] fontWithIdentifier:self.currentFontIdentifier];
}
```

You may not need `currentFontIdentifier` property since it can be obtained with `_fontIdentifiers[_currentSelectedIndex]`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the methods 'indexOfObject and 'lastObject' of the NSArray class, something like:

Using an array of sizes:

```
NSArray *fontList = @[@"12","14","18"];
```

Then you could iterate through it using the indexOfObject

```
NSUInteger ix = [fontList indexOfObject:self.currentFontIdentifier] + 1;
if ([[fontList lastObject] isEqual:self.currentFontIdentifier])
    ix=0;
self.currentFontIdentifier = [fontList objectAtIndex:ix];
```

or

```
NSUInteger ix = [fontList indexOfObject:self.currentFontIdentifier] + 1;
if (ix >= [fontList count])
    ix=0;
self.currentFontIdentifier = [fontList objectAtIndex:ix];
```